# Where can I post proposal-specific Area 51 questions?

Tags: support, area-51

**Background:** Area 51 has recently gone from using *comments* for each proposal to a [site-wide discussion format](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com).

**Question:** Where do proposal-specific questions go (like [this one](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23/please-can-all-followers-and-visitors-vote-on-the-questions-here))? Another example: we've had an extensive discussion about the [name of one proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikipedia-and-wikis) - where should that go?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think questions like the first one are desirable. Mind explaining?

Comment: @Borror0 - yes, sure. I originally saw this on another site (sorry, can't find the link) that was close to the Commitment phase. The proposer asked people to re-arrange their votes (which were distributed across multiple questions) to get the 5 on + 5 off topic questions. That inspired me to ask the followers (many of which have joined in the last week or so) to get voting to get that number up. After all, I thought that if they were new (and many were new to the whole Stack Exchange concept) they would not know what was expected of them. It was *not* intended to be site wide spam!

Comment: @Wikis: But why the rush to enter commitment? Even if there are finally 60 followers, the proposal will need at least 200 more before having enough to exit commitment. Taking a bit more time defining the site won't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Borror0 - well, at six months so far, we're hardly rushing! But we need first 60 followers and 10 questions, and *then* we go to the 200 followers in the *next phase* (commitment). Also - turn it around - what's *wrong* with asking the *followers* to vote (especially since many are new)?

Comment: @Wikis: It's unnecessary, which is probably why Robert called it spam.

Comment: @Borrow0 I think Robert called it spam because it was *site wide*.

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked to was correctly closed - you need to drum up support for the proposal elsewhere.

As for your question about the name I don't see why it can't go on the discussion site. You are, after all, discussing the proposal. However, I'm not in charge of the system and the process so treat my answer as an informed guess rather than the "truth".

Comment: please see comment above.